# Spring JPA Repository - querying three tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have three tables.

One User can have many jobs and One User can have many transactions.
SO the tables are : User, Jobs and Transactions.
If given the job Name I want to find the Transactions information for the date ( the date is in Transaction ) 
How do I write this query in the Repository ?
i.e 
This job name is related to X User, on Date  Y, what transactions did he make ?

```
Users
private long id;
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy= user)
private Set<Jobs> job= new HashSet<Jobs>();
@OneToMany(mappedBy= user)
private Set<Transactions> transactions = new HashSet<Transactions>;

Job
private long id;
private String name;
@ManyToOne
private Users user;

Transactions
private long id;
private Date created;
private String price;
private String product;
@ManyToOne
private Users user;
```

I need to create a Service that given the job name and the transaction date; it shows the price and the product.

Created three corresponding repositories that extend JPA repository.
Where would I write the query and do I use @Query annotation, or is there some Spring JPA method that implements such query?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I cannot see how jobs and transactions are linked?

Comment: with spring-data, you would wirte a "finder" method in your (Transactions) repository interface (e.g. `List<Transactions> findByCreatedAndUser_Name(Date date, String name)`...spring data will compile the query for you.

Comment: Jobs and transactions are linked through the user. If I have a job, can find the user id and then using that find the transaction. Like if I had all three tables joined I would have : user id, transaction id and info, job id and info in one row.@xerx593 that query would find it by the Created field and the name of the user. I need to find it using the name field of the job table. Thank you !

Comment: ..aok, (since "finder" methods dont support "join"/ and jpql no subquerying at all) you should use `@Query` (also more flexible with the return type `List<Object[]>`) annotation like `select t.price, t.product from User u join u.job as j join u.transactions as t where j.name = ? and t.created = ?` ..as i understand the query now